# Como agrupar elementos por meses en vue

Tags: javascript, array, firebase, vue.js, vuex

Tengo un conjunto de datos similares a esto:

```
[{fecha: '01/06/2018', pago: '30', id: '-LDviH9T9XripkL64-8y'}, {fecha: '02/06/2018', pago: '20', id: '-LDviH9T93spkL64-8y'}].
```

¿Cómo podría hacer para agrupar los elementos por meses y sumar los totales? Por ejemplo:

**[50,20,40,50,20,40,40,20,12,21]**

Que cada elemento sea el total de el mes.
Este es mi codigo:

```
totalEgreso2() {
            return this.$store.getters.getCargarCheckIn.reduce(function (total, item, index, array){

             return total + item.pago

            },{})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De una manera muy simple podría servir:

```js
let data = [
  {fecha: '01/06/2018', pago: '30', id: '-LDviH9T9XripkL64-8y'},
  {fecha: '02/06/2018', pago: '20', id: '-LDviH9T93spkL64-8y'}
];

function totalEgreso2() {
  let sum = 0;
  data.forEach(item => {
    sum += Number(item.pago);
  });
  return sum;

}

totalEgreso2();
```